# How to define a yasnippet whose content depends on the value of an Elisp variable?

Tags: yasnippet

I want to define a yasnippet for `shell-script` mode that would insert a chunk of text whose content depends on the setting of the `sh-shell` variable.

Since the possible different text insertions are several lines long, and are quite different from each other, so doing this with conditional fields of the form

```
${N:`(case sh-shell (zsh  "foo")
                    (bash "bar")
                    (sh   "baz")
                    (t    "frobozz"))`}
```

...would all but eliminate the convenient formatting one this sort of template for.

**EDIT:** To clarify: the code above is not useful to me, because I need to insert multi-line formatted text, not little, one-word strings like `"foo"`, `"bar"`, etc.

---

If I were to use an unholy mix of Elisp and `bash` to represent what I'm looking for, this is how I'd represent it:

```
`(case sh-shell (zsh <<EOZSH)
zsh version
    of
    snippet
    looks
    like
    this
EOZSH
                   (bash <<EOBASH)
bash version of snippet looks like this
EOZSH
                   (sh   <<EOSH)
sh
 version
  of
   snippet
    looks
     like
      this
EOSH
                   (t    <<EODEFAULT)
default version
  of snippet
    looks
    like
    this
EOSH
)`
```

IOW, the snippet would consist of a single embedded Elisp `case` expression, where the key of each key-value pair is a possible value of `sh-shell`, and the value is a (formatted) snippet/template; I've represented the latter using (totally invalid) `heredoc` notation.

---

Is there a (syntactically sound) way to implement this idea?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the first version. The multi-line formatting is only visible in the snippet definition, where arguably it's a good thing as it makes it easy to read your code. The expansion is still just one line long. I think `case` won't work though, if `sh-shell` takes string values. `case` compares via `eql`, which only returns true if the arguments are the same lisp object, not if they are different objects with the same value.

Comment: @Tyler: sorry for the confusion; I've edited my post to clarify things.

Comment: You can still use the same code, replacing foo etc with a multi-line string. Unless you need to dynamically manipulate the indentation of your inserted text, I don't know what a better approach would be.

Answer (score 2):

You can call any elisp function from your snippet definition, so if you can use a helper function defined in your init file to keep the snippet file tidier. In your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(defun snippet-helper ()
  (cond ((string-equal sh-shell "zsh") "foo")
        ((string-equal sh-shell "bash") "bar")
        ((string-equal sh-shell "sh") "baz")
        (t "foo")))
```

(note that the `case` form doesn't work when comparing strings that aren't the same object, so I used `cond` instead).

Then your snippet becomes:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: hhh
# key: hhh
# --
${N:`(snippet-helper)`}
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work if your replacement strings contain multiple spaces to align the different lines. Extra spaces get removed by a call to `(yas--indent snippet)`. Not sure how to fix this yet.